# 'active' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

Anyone know why i am getting that error, i got this error when i upgrade my project to newest version of unity3d.

```js
#pragma strict
@script ExecuteInEditMode
function Start () {

}

var bool : boolean = false;
var ts1 : Transform[];
function Update () {
 if(bool){
  bool = false;
  var ts = new Array();
  for(var trans : Transform in transform){
   if(!trans.active){
    ts.Add(trans);
   }
  }
  ts1 = new Array(ts.Count);
  for(var i=0; i<ts.length; i++){
   ts1[i] = ts[i];
  }
 }
}
```

Tell me which part of the code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this property not exist.
Instead of transform.active you need to use gameobject.activeself to check the active status.

```
#pragma strict
@script ExecuteInEditMode
function Start () {

}

var bool : boolean = false;
var ts1 : Transform[];
function Update () {
    if(bool){
        bool = false;
        var ts = new Array();
        for(var trans : Transform in transform){
            if(!trans.gameObject.activeSelf){
                ts.Add(trans);
            }
        }
        ts1 = new Array(ts.Count);
        for(var i=0; i<ts.length; i++){
            ts1[i] = ts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it fix, how about this part im getting error with this UIStone.transform.parent.active = true; , i just try to change in activeSelf but getting error

Answer (score 0):

Active is not a property. You need to use the `activeSelf` property from the type `GameObject`.

```
transform.gameObject.activeSelf
```

You can also use:

```
transform.gameObject.activeInHierarchy
```

To fix your code, replace this

```
if(!trans.active){
    ts.Add(trans);
}
```

With this

```
if(!trans.gameObject.activeSelf ){
    ts.Add(trans);
}
```

Comment: active is not a property of gameobject... active not exist. the property is activeSelf